# Angular RC5: Can't bind to 'myDirective' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: angular

I tried to migrate my project to RC5 and use NgModules, but i'm facing problem with references to custom directives.

It throws following exception:

```
"Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'myDirective' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.
```

Here is a plunker that shows the issue:
http://plnkr.co/edit/kZ7bcjmM57tuH3Zzl4wk

Anybody could help me figure out what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data binding can only be used if there is an input or output with a matching name.

Your directive is missing

```
 @Input() myDirective:boolean;
```

for

```
 [myDirective]="true"
```

to work.

Without this you can apply the directive like

```
<div myDirective>
```

but you can't do data binding to inputs of the directive if there are none.

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/n8oQ0vuMdeN8WjVfaFjK?p=preview)